# Codeigniter 2 buttons in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is my question 'if(!empty($_POST['btn_editinventory]))' is working but if i click on btndeleteinventory it will also execute the codes in my btneditinventory. Anyone knows how will i correct my condition in my controller if you have two buttons in the view like this:

```
    <input type="button" value="Edit" name="btn_editinventory" id="btn_editinventory" onclick="validate_editinventory();"/>
   <input type="button" value="Delete" name="btn_deleteinventory" id="btn_deleteinventory" onclick="validate_deleteinventory();"/>
```

Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Here is my view

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/mystyle.css') ?>">

<div id="content">
<form action="edit_delete_others2" method="POST" id='frm_otherequips2' name="frm_otherequips2">
    <fieldset id="edit_other">
        <legend>Inventory Details</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <?php $otherequips = $other2->Equipment;
                      $otherdesc = $other2->ItemDescription;
                      $otherID = $other2->ID;
                      $otherserialnum = $other2->SerialNumber;
                ?>
                <td>Equipment</td>
                <?php // if(isset($other)) { ?>
                <td><input type="text" id="txt_editotherequip" name="txt_editotherequip" value="<?php echo $otherequips // echo (isset($other->Equipment) AND $other->Equipment) ? $other->Equipment:'';  ?>"/></td>

                <td>Item Description</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txt_editotherdesc" name="txt_editotherdesc" value="<?php echo $otherdesc //  echo (isset($other->ItemDescription) AND $other->ItemDescription) ? $other->ItemDescription:'';  ?>"/></td>
                <td style="visibility: hidden;"><input type="text" id="txt_editotherID" name="txt_editotherID" value="<?php echo $otherID  //echo (isset($other->ID) AND $other->ID) ? $other->ID:'';  ?>"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Serial Number</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txt_editotherserialnum" name="txt_editotherserialnum" value="<?php echo $otherserialnum // echo (isset($other->SerialNumber) AND $other->SerialNumber)  ? $other->SerialNumber:'';  ?>"/></td>
                <?php // } ?>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button"  id="btn_editother" name="btn_editother" value="Edit" onclick="validate_edit_otherequip();"/></td>
                <td><input type="button" id="btn_deleteother" name="btn_deleteother" class="btn_deleteother" value="Delete" onclick="validate_delete_otherequip();"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

here is my javascript:

```
<script>
function validate_edit_otherequip(){
    if(document.getElementById('txt_editotherequip').value === ""){
        alert('Please Input Equipment!');
        return false;
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('txt_editotherdesc').value === ""){
        alert('Please Input Item Description');
        return false;
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('txt_editotherserialnum').value === ""){
        alert('Please Input Serial Number');
        return false;
    }
    else{
        var y;
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to save updated data?") === true){
            var y = document.forms['frm_otherequips2'].submit();
        }
        else if(confirm("Are you sure you want to save updated data?") === false){
            return false;
        }
    }
}

function validate_delete_otherequip(){
    var x;
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this data?") === true){
        var x = document.forms['frm_otherequips2'].submit();
    }
    else if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this data?") === false){
        return false;
    }
}
```

and here is my controller:

```
public function edit_delete_others2($id){
            $data_other['other2'] = $this->inventory_model->other_search($id);
            $this->load->view('homeview');
            $this->load->view('frm_otherequips2', $data_other);
            $this->load->view('footer_view');
}
```

I don't know how to have a condition in buttons.

Comment: Can you post the complete html code?

Comment: how are you submitting the form?

Comment: Searock I've edited my question, you can see my whole program now.

Answer (score 0):

As far as your two buttons have a name attribute, it's pretty easy to handle in your Controller

```
public function edit_delete_others2($id){

    if($this->input->post('btn_editinventory')) {

        // Do your edit stuff

    } elseif($this->input->post('btn_deleteinventory')) { 

        // Do your delete stuff
    }
}
```

The button is never send in the post when you don't click on it, this is why it works